# How to write angular directive that toggles classes by selector

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to write a directive that toggles classes based on a selector condition:

```
<label class-when="{'is-checked': ':has(input:checked)', 'is-disabled': ':has(input:disabled)'}">
    <input type="checkbox">
    Example checkbox
</label>
```

I need to somehow watch for DOM changes on the element and its descendents but I'm getting an [`ng:areq` error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq). How can I do this?

```
define(function (require) {
    var _ = require('lodash');

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            object: '@classWhen'
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.$watchCollection(function() {
                return element.find('*').add(element);
            }, function () {
                _.forOwn(scope.object, function (test, classes) {
                    test = typeof test === 'boolean' ? test : element.is(test);
                    element.toggleClass(classes, test);
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Just curious.  Why are you trying to add classes like this with angular?  Would a jQuery or even a css solution be a better approach?

Comment: @ryanyuyu I would assume that a directive is required because of a structural directive on a parent element, or the element itself (that is just not shown in the code provided). I could be wrong, though

Comment: Personally, if I'm having to dig this far into the link function of a directive, I typically just switch to jQuery.  I don't currently see how this directive would interact with an angular controller.  JQuery was built for direct DOM manipulation, whereas angular is better for data interactions and databinding.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I'm doing it in angular because I need to use it in an angular application. The example shows an input but I want the directive to be as generic as possible. The advantage to using the directive versus jQuery alone is that the directive to dynamically change and retest the classes

Comment: I have solved one major issue for you, which is that your `scope.object` is a string, so doing `_.forOwn()` gives you each character in the string with an index as the key. To fix this, you need to do a `JSON.parse()` on `scope.object`, which leads to the next issue. Your string is invalid JSON because it has single quotes surrounding the properties/values and it needs double quotes to be valid JSON. The issue then remains that your directive does not fire when the user checks/unchecks the checkbox. I'm still working on that part, but I think i've given you a big step in the right direction

Comment: Or just use the two way `"="` binding for the scope.object.

Comment: All this is just wrong from angular view. You should never do things like this. If you want container style to depend on inputs - directives should be on each input element, not one magic directive on top.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov If the directive is on the input element, how are you going to get a class applied to the `<label>`?

Comment: @ryanve Check my updated solution

Comment: I have to agree with @PetrAveryanov. Angular is all about the model. The model should also determine the state of the checkbox e.g., so there is no need for dealing with CSS selectors. If you have to watch for DOM changes then you have no Angular application.

Comment: You described a solution to a problem, but didn't tell us the actual problem.  Perhaps there is a solution to your problem other than the one your proposed.  If your example is indicative of your problem, then I can solve this for your purely in markup.  However if your problem is actually much bigger, than I could solve this with a combination of several custom directives.  Can you elaborate on the problem?

Comment: @ryanve Please look at my answer below and hope it will work for your solution as it used the RequireJS as same as you.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, after reading your bounty comment, I understand that you want this to be controller independent. I spent some time completely reworking my solution, and I think I have finally figured out a way to accomplish what you want.

It really comes down to 2 things:

1) Detecting a change on the checkbox `:checked` status, and

2) Detecting a change on the checkbox `:disabled` status

Detecting `1)` was easy, as you can use a simple jQuery change handler, but detecting `2)` took a bit more research. It requires the use of `scope.$watch` on the child `ng-disabled` attribute.

Here is a demo of how this would work:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
  .directive("classWhen", function() {
    function setClasses(classWhen, $element, $input) {
      Object.keys(classWhen).forEach(function(key) {
        var test = classWhen[key];
        // .toggleClass("className", true) === .addClass("className")
        // .toggleClass("className", false) === .removeClass("className")
        $element.toggleClass(key, $element.is(test));
      });
    }
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function link (scope, element, attrs) {
        var classWhen = JSON.parse(attrs.classWhen);
        var $element = $(element);
        $element.find("*").each(function (index, elem) {
          var $elem = $(this);
          // namespace the change event so we can easily .off() it
          $elem.off("change.classWhen");
          $elem.on("change.classWhen", function () {
            setClasses(classWhen, $element, $elem);
          });
          // watch child ng-disabled attribute
          scope.$watch($elem.attr("ng-disabled"), function (val) {
            setClasses(classWhen, $element, $elem);
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.is-checked {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.is-disabled {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="disableAll" />Disable All</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label class-when='{"is-checked": ":has(input:checked)", "is-disabled": ":has(input:disabled)"}'>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="disableAll">Example checkbox 1
  </label>
  <br>
  <label class-when='{"is-checked": ":has(input:checked)", "is-disabled": ":has(input:disabled)"}'>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="disableAll">Example checkbox 2
  </label>
  <br>
  <label class-when='{"is-checked": ":has(input:checked, .test)", "is-disabled": ":has(input:disabled)"}'>
    <input type="text" ng-disabled="disableAll" ng-class="testingClass" ng-model="testingClass"/>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="disableAll">
    Example checkbox 3
  </label>
  <br>
  <label class-when='{"is-checked": ":has(input:checked)", "is-disabled": ":has(input:disabled)"}'>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-disabled="disableAll">Example checkbox 4
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer! This seems to work in the snippet runner but i still get the `ng:areq` error when in my angular environment

Comment: @ryanve [ng:areq](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq) is a generic error for a bad argument. It obviously is not an issue with my code, so I have no way to debug your issue unless you post more details about it. Can you give me a line number, the extended description of the error, and the related code in the area? Or better yet, can you post a fiddle that reproduces the error?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt to solve your problem in generic way: https://plnkr.co/edit/kVyJQClmQhF3FeBTmKaX?p=preview

Directive code:

```
app.directive('classWhen', () => (scope, element, attrs) => {
  scope.$watchCollection(getClasses, setClasses)

  function getClasses() {
    // We have to evaluate expression in attrs.classWhen so that we get object
    const rawClasses = scope.$eval(attrs.classWhen)
    const classes = {}

    // then we normalize it so that strings are treated as jquery selectors
    Object.keys(rawClasses).forEach((className) => {
      const expr = rawClasses[className]
      classes[className] = typeof expr === 'string'
        ? element.is(expr)
        : !!expr // we normalize falsy values to booleans
    })

    // then we return it to $watchCollection
    return classes
  }

  /**
   * will be called whenever any of the classes changes
   */
  function setClasses(classes) {
    Object.keys(classes).forEach((className) => {
      element.toggleClass(className, classes[className])
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: @ryanve does it solve your problem? How can I improve my answer?

Comment: I like the simplicity of this approach but depending on how the DOM changes it take a few seconds to work. Like as if it waits for the next digest

Comment: The problem with this solution, is the same as one of my original solutions to this (if you look at the edit history on my answer). #1, it does not handle multiple checkboxes individually, and #2, it relies on controller variables, which the OP stated in the bounty comment: "I'd like to do this in a generic directive or filter *that does not require anything from a controller*"

Comment: @ryanve what do you mean by *how the DOM changes*? Can you provide an example plunk where it behaves like that? My guess is that you're changing it from outside of digest. In my plunk I added `ng-model` to the input exactly because it solves triggering digest whenever input value changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a generic fiddle for this and also with RequireJS as you used.

Please have a look here

http://fiddle.jshell.net/balasuar/dugmu/15/

Note: Whatever property you added in the selector like `:checked` and `:disabled`, add the related angular property to the child element like `ng-model` and `ng-disabled`. It will work like a charm !!

**Code**

```js
var app = window.app = angular.module("myApp", []);

define('classWhenDirective', function () {
    //var _ = require('lodash');
    var app = window.app;debugger;
    app.directive("classWhen", function() {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(getChanges, setClasses)

  function getChanges() {
    var attrs = [];
    
    function getAttrs(elm) {
       $.each(elm.attributes, function(i, attrib){
     var name = attrib.name;
     var value = attrib.value;
       if(value && name.indexOf('ng-') > -1) {
         value = scope.$eval(value);
       }
     if(value) {      
       attrs.push(name + ':' + value);
     }
  });
     
    }
    
    getAttrs(element.get(0));
    
    element.children().each(function(){
       getAttrs(this);
    });
    
    return attrs.join(',');
  }

  function setClasses() {
    var rawClasses = scope.$eval(attrs.classWhen);

    Object.keys(rawClasses).forEach(function(className){
      var expr = rawClasses[className]
      var setClass = typeof expr === 'string'
        ? element.is(expr)
        : !!expr;
       element.toggleClass(className, setClass);
    });
  }
    }
  };   
    });
});

define('todo', ['classWhenDirective'], function() {
  var app = window.app;
  app.controller('myController', function($scope) {

  });
});

// angular bootstrap
require(['todo'], function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

```css
.is-checked {
  color: green;
}
.is-disabled {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.0.6/minified/require.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h2>ClassWhen Directive</h2>

<div ng-controller="myController">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="disableAll" />Disable All</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label class-when='{"is-checked": ":has(input:checked)", "is-disabled": ":has(input:disabled)"}'>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkBox1" ng-disabled="disableAll">ClassWhen checkbox 1
  </label>
  <br>
  <label class-when='{"is-checked": ":has(input:checked)", "is-disabled": ":has(input:disabled)"}'>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkBox2" ng-disabled="disableAll">ClassWhen checkbox 2
  </label>
</div>
```